# Are 'than before' and 'than previously' interchangeable?

Tags: word-choice

> Work is progressing at a faster rate than before/previously.

Can either 'before' or 'previously' be used in this example?

Comment: Yes, either one works.

Comment: I'd say **than before** sounds a lot more natural than **than previously**. For some reason ending the sentence on **than previously** sounds awkward.